# "undefined" attributes in webmap

Tags: qgis2web

I am trying to make a basic web map for my employer showing all past projects completed in the state. The map (via qgis2web plugin version 2.33.1, leaflet option) itself is created fine, but the data within the attribute table is not carrying over to the webmap, giving all of my attributes the value of "undefined". Dataset is not huge; I tried hiding all but one to see if that would work, but no luck.

The reason I am using leaflet is because my map would not show up at all in OpenLayers, so if anyone has advice there too I'm all ears!

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: I think we need to see the data. If you can upload a single layer which fails, someone can try to recreate the error, and hence investigate.

Comment: Absolutely, @Tom. I'm new to Stack Exchange and couldn't figure out how to directly upload a zip file, so here's a link to access the data (hopefully!): [data](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/pNAxN9TgoP1QuV5NgYAOIYeEnzPT6LrGShbuHLvaSXI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your column headers contains ' #', I've created a new file without this suffix and it's working.